# ASP Site .net 2.0 interact with WebService 1.1

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services

Well the thing I want to know is probably quite simple and it must be a Yes it is possible or No it's impossible.

Here it goes, I've been asked here to create a WebService that will work on .NET framework 1.1 so other project can interact with it to get the job a little .dll(1.1 also) can do.

The main idea behind this is to be able to upgrade the application and the rest of the projects while being able to use this old .dll through the WebService.

Is it possible to comunicate with a WebService that works on the framework 1.1 from an ASP application working on 2.0 or higher.

Actually, what I've tried raise an error like so :
The request failed with the state HTTP:401 : Access Denied.

But when I access the webservice(asmx page), it does work, the page shows all the method available. Also the project build perfectly.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself, and for those who wants to know, Yes it is possible. I created another project with a simpler WebService and this one does work.

Comment: The problem was in the web.config.